# Will something happen when reputation reaches 100k?

Tags: discussion, reputation

What will happen when reputation reaches 100k? Nothing or something?

Answer (score 2):

You've quadrupled our [maximum privilege level](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/privileges), so I'm not aware of any other change -- being rather short of it myself :)

I can [offer this](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/64726335#64726335):

> Congratulations to Tim, who has just topped 100k reputation points on
> U&L!

Your curiosity has gotten you far!

Comment: Thanks. I don't know whether I am more happy or sad

Answer (score 1):

Used to be that you would get some swag, but that seems to be on hold: [Swag is coming back! (indefinitely paused)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/358195/swag-is-coming-back-indefinitely-paused). Other than that there were no changes when I reached 100k on Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: Interesting link from that page. Eight users listed with 1M+ reputation - although none are on U&L.

Comment: Only SO, and somehow, TeX.SE, have the levels of traffic required for users to get enough upvotes and bonuses to hit a million points. On the rest of SE, Unix.SE does quite well, and I think Gilles is the second-highest-ranked participant anywhere outside of SO; but at current rates it will still take four or five years to reach a million.